# newbie: activerecord joins ? some help converting sql to activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, relation

Im trying to figure out how to do:

- group
  has_many participants
- participant
  belongs_to group
- user
  has_profile
- profile
  belongs_to user

**Now Im trying to get all the participants from a group where group.id ='1' and where  participant.profile.gender = 'x'**

How would this convert to active record? I have digged the docs but not a sql guru and not a AR guru at all. anyone can point me in right direction? that would be very helpful to understand how to do this. *confused*

Comment: are partecipants users or profiles?

Comment: participant is only user_id group_id created_at updated_at based on user_id I grab there profile and then profile.gender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like

```
 Participant.where(:group_id => 1).where(:profile=>{:gender=>'x'})
```

Update: since participant is a join table you would need to change that:

```
 Participant.where(:group_id => 1).where(:user=>{:profile=>{:gender=>'x'}})
```

you would also need to add a belongs_to :user to Participant

Comment: thx tried that now I see how it should be done very clean in rails. but then Participant Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `participants`.* FROM `participants` WHERE `participants`.`group_id` = 1 AND `profile`.`gender` = 'male'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'profile.gender' in 'where clause': SELECT `participants`.* FROM `participants`  WHERE `participants`.`group_id` = 1 AND `profile`.`gender` = 'male'
I get that error while profile.gender exists, added relations any idea why that breaks?

Comment: is the table is named profiles?  in that case try pluralizing it in the where clause.  You may also need to add .includes(:users).includes(:profiles)

Comment: One more note:  If you know the exact sql that will get you the results you want, you can use find_by_sql.  You give up some portability but it is often faster than using "the Rails way"